# Expand RecyclerView so that it doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a form type interface where there will be a list of items inside of the form. I'm using `RecyclerView` to render the list of items. This form is also scrollable. I want to avoid nested scrolling so I want to expand all of the `RecylerView` items so that it is always at its maximum size (the sum of all the heights of its items plus margins and paddings). How can I accomplish this programmatically (or through XML) ?

Comment: What's the `parent` of your RecyclerView?